# MySQL ORDER BY optimization when sorting NULLs and '' last - is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sorting, null, sql-order-by

I've been trying to optimize an awkward ORDER BY in MySQL. The issue is that I want NULLs and blank fields '' to appear at the bottom rather than the top. I've come up with:

```
ORDER BY isnull(if (isnull(Lastname) OR ascii(Lastname)=0, null, 1)), Lastname ASC,
isnull(if (isnull(Firstname) OR ascii(Firstname)=0, null, 1)), Firstname ASC;
```

But this is causing a filesort, accessing all the rows in the table :(

By creating an index of (Lastname, Firstname) I'm able to optimize the query to be lightening fast with a simple sort:

```
ORDER BY Lastname ASC, Firstname ASC;
```

No filesort :)

It appears that MySQL does not let you change the default sorting for NULLs, and there is no NULLS LAST option. Is it impossible for me to optimize the original sort?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's only suitable when someone provides a workable solution

Answer (score 1):

How about this workaround?

```
( SELECT * FROM 
    WHERE Lastname IS NOT NULL AND Firstname IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY Lastname ASC, Firstname ASC ) 
UNION 
( SELECT * FROM 
    WHERE Lastname IS NULL OR Firstname IS NULL 
    ORDER BY Lastname ASC, Firstname ASC );
```

---

If above query is too slow, then it must be needed a new reference column - like `hasnull` - to make sort faster. The column will be updated while inserting or updating. Create an index with `hasnull, Lastname, Firstname` and use it on sorting.

Comment: Unfortunately that takes much longer. The table has a LOT of rows. Although to two sorts are in the derived tables are fast, the union itself is slow :(

Comment: I added another suggestion. Sorry for your disappointment. :(

Comment: Unfortunately the code base is large, the prospect of adding a column that needs to be updated with every insert/update isn't nice. Although your first suggestion has actually lead to a realisation of the solution. Forget the union, just do it as 2 separate queries, with the appropriate multi key indexes both queries return in under a second even on the large table. Rather than answer my own question, do you want to update your response with this? Then I'll accept it as the solution :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It looks like I didn't give you a meaningful answer. If you got a hint from my answer, it's enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered concatenating firstname and lastname columns, then sorting on the combination of both?

```
mysql> select *, CONCAT_WS(' ', fname, lname) as fullname  from order_by_neg_test order by fullname desc;

+----+-------+-------+---------+--------------+
| id | value | fname | lname   | fullname     |
+----+-------+-------+---------+--------------+
|  4 |    -1 | mike  | purcell | mike purcell |
|  3 |     0 | NULL  | jenkins | jenkins      |
|  5 |    17 | chris | NULL    | chris        |
|  1 |    45 | NULL  | NULL    |              |
|  2 |     1 | NULL  | NULL    |              |
|  6 |    27 |       | NULL    |              |
|  7 |    -1 | NULL  | NULL    |              |
+----+-------+-------+---------+--------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That's got a nice output. But it's a filesort and slow.

Comment: You really have rows where first name and last name can be null? Maybe you should implement tighter data validation before passing to database. You could try using a DESC vs ASC, as DESC will push the null values to the bottom.

Comment: I've done tests where the columns are not null. It still resorts in a filesort as you need to use string functions to get the empty strings to the bottom in a ASC sort. The only think I've found to be fast and effective is a multi query solution with appropriate multi key indexes.

Comment: So you are doing the multiple queries and parsing at the app layer then?

Comment: Not parsing to sort if that's what you mean, that would be way to slow. I'm grabbing sorted results from the DB minus nulls and '', then where Lastname isn't blank but firstname is, vice versa, then the blanks. These 4 queries sort off the index (lastname, firstname) so return in well under a second. Much, much faster than using any MySQL sorting tricks to get the nulls and '' to the bottom. The app then loops as it normally would, just treating the 4 queries as one. I only wanted the first 100 rows, so it may only do the first query, depends on how many results are returned.

Comment: @Cosmicnet: Makes sense. Optimizing the app by shifting logic from the database to the application. 4 queries is still 4 queries though, perhaps cache the results to limit hits to your database, or set-up a master-slave setup and query against the slave.